# Bulgarian Mathematical Olympiad Round 4 problem 1.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

**Problem**: Prove that there exists a unique triple of positive integers greater than 1 such that product of any two increased by one is divisible by the third number.

I found $(2,3,7)$ to satisfy this but cant prove this. Please help.

Comment: Please give the contest this comes from.  It will help to know what level of  math is expected in the solution.  Can you prove that the three integers are distinct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clearly all numbers must be pairwise coprime, let them be $a<b<c$

Notice that $abc| ab+ac+bc+1$ and so $abc\leq ab+ac+bc+1$.

Notice that if $a\geq 3$ then $abc\geq 3bc> ab+ac+bc+1$ and so $a=2$.

It follows that $b|2c+1$ and $c|2b+1$ and so $bc|2b+2c+1$ In particular $bc\leq 2b+2c+1$.

It $b\geq 4$ then  $bc\geq 4c>2b+2c+1$ and so $b=3$.

Hence $a=2,b=3$. And finally we must have $c|2\times 3+1$. So $c=7$.

Comment: how does $abc|ab+bc+ca+1$?

Comment: Because each of $a,b,c$ divides it, and they're coprime.

Comment: yeah, that :) ${}$